# Why is tail recursive Collatz conjecture causing stack overflow in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, stack-overflow, guile, collatz

I've written Collatz conjecture in Scheme:

```
(define C
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
     ((eq? n 1) 1)
     ((even? n) (C (/ n 2)))
     (else (C (+ (* n 3) 1))))))
```

This is a tail recursive call, yet I get stack overflow when I call (C 121):

```
guile> (trace C)
(C)
guile> (C 121)
[C 121]
[C 364]
[C 182]
[C 91]
[C 274]
[C 137]
[C 412]
[C 206]
[C 103]
[C 310]
[C 155]
[C 466]
[C 233]
[C 700]
[C 350]
[C 175]
[C 526]
[C 263]
[C 790]
[C 395]
[C 1186]
ERROR: Stack overflow
ABORT: (stack-overflow)
```

Why is proper tail recursion causing an overflow? As you can see, I'm using Guile as a Scheme interpreter (version 1.8.7).

Comment: What happens when you do not trace the function call? What happens when you use another scheme system?

Comment: Disabling trace doesn't help. Racket does fine with the given example.

Comment: This might be a bug: that definition looks tail-recursive.  (Most tracing libraries will destroy the tail-recursiveness, though.)

Comment: I tried this on ubuntu and it seems to be working fine. Which OS you are using?

Comment: This is on openSUSE 11.3, but I think this may be fault of older version of Guile (2.x versions are available, but not for my system). Anyway, if this definition is correct that everything is OK, I was afraid I misunderstood something about tail recursion.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried this in guile-2.0.1 and guile-1.8.5, without tracing, and got no stack overflow

Comment: Works fine guile 1.8.7 on Debian amd64. http://pastebin.com/8EYDwpY1

Comment: For what it's worth, it worked with TinyScheme 1.39, on Solaris SPARC 32-bit.

Comment: am I the only one botherd by it only ever returning `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure as defined works fine in Racket. It seems like a bug to me, or something very specific to your environment.

Almost certainly not related to your problem, but a bit of nit-picking: use the comparison `(= n 1)` for numbers instead of `(eq? n 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define C
  (lambda (n)
    (cond
     ((eq? n 1) 1)
     ((even? n) (C (/ n 2)))
     (else (C (+ (* n 3) 1))))))
```

This looks like it always returns `1` (or loops infinitely -- the conjecture remains unproven). Is there a transcription error hiding a `(+1 ...)` around the recursive calls?